# HTML/JavaScript Tree with text input

Tags: javascript, html, input, tree

I need to build a webpage which will be in a tree structure but with text input fields. Is there any JavaScript library available? The data needs to come from the server and after the inputs are added they need to be submitted back to server. The server will be Java based web/app server mostly tomcat.

Comment: You mean something like http://drupal.org using the book feature?

Comment: [This](https://www.jstree.com/) library may be what you're looking for